# Multiple views modifying one object MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building a service which requires a somewhat lengthy setup process.  I have it broken into 4 models and 4 corresponding views.  They are Setup, Setup2, Setup3, and Setup4.  Each of these views gathers information from the user which is stored in a User object.  I have been passing the user along like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Setup(FormCollection values)
    {
        User registeringUser = new User();

        registeringUser.email = User.Identity.Name;
        registeringUser.fName = values["fName"];
        registeringUser.lName = values["lName"];
        registeringUser.phone = values["phone"];

        return RedirectToAction("/Setup2", registeringUser);
    }
```

For some reason, this seems to work just fine for the first jump (from Setup to Setup2) but after that I'm getting weird behavior, such as User. getting set to null when the User is passed to another View.

---

In a related, but slightly different issue, I need the last screen (Setup4) to be recursive.  This screen adds a course in which the user is enrolled, and if they don't check the "This was my last class" button, it needs to basically clear the form so they can enter another course.

The entire Controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Setup4(FormCollection values, User registeringUser)
    {
        // values["allClassesAdded"] returns "false" as a string if box is unchecked, returns "true,false" if checked.
        // Solution: parse string for "true"
        if (utils.parseForTrue(values["allClassesAdded"]))
        {
            // TODO Redirect to "congratulations you're done" page.
            database.CreateUserInDB(registeringUser);
            return Redirect("/Home");
        }
        else
        {
            // Build course and add it to the list in the User
            course c = new course(values);

            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //registeringUser.currentCourses.Add(c);
                registeringUser.AddCourse(c);
                return RedirectToAction("/Setup4", registeringUser); // <---- This doesn't really work right
                //return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/Account/Login");
            }


        }
    }
```

This is my first project with MVC, so if you find that I'm doing the entire thing completely incorrectly, feel free to not answer the question I asked and offer the proper solution to this need.  I'm moving an existing (pure) C# project to MVC and I'm mainly just stuck on how to work within MVC's interesting structure.  I'm very grateful for any help you can give!

Thanks!

Comment: without seeing what is in Setup2 [HttpGet] method, it will be difficult to say whats happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store user related data in [session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) without passing it between requests

Smth like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step1(Step1Model model)
{
   Session["UserRegistration"] = new UserRegistration
   {
      FirstName = model.fName,
      ....
   }
   ....
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step2(Step2Model model)
{
   var userRegistration = Session["UserRegistration"] as UserRegistration;
   if (userRegistration == null) { return Redirrect("Step1"); }
   userRegistration.SomeField = model.someField;
   ...
   Session["UserRegistration"]  = userRegistration;
   ....
}
```

Comment: Another option would be using js, for example [this plugin](http://www.jquery-steps.com/), so u don't have to make requests to server between steps

Comment: This worked very well.  I was surprised how easy it was to implement as well.  Thanks for the clear and straightforward answer!